# Почему не подключается сайт на серевер apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2

вот конфиг подключения 
cremea.lc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName cremea.lc
    ServerAlias www.cremea.lc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cremea.lc
    ErrorLog /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/cremea.lc>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

вот etc/host

```
127.0.0.1   cremea.lc
```

`a2ensite` и `service apache2 reload` делал `mod_retwite` тоже подключен. Даже комп перегружал.  Но набираю в браузере `cremea.lc` и получаю страницу проблема с загрузкой страницы сервер не найден  что я делаю не так ?

Comment: `a2ensite` не забыли?

Comment: права прописаны? `chown` `chmod`